# How to specify a filename and filepath as a key value pair in json and passed as an input parameter to a Rest call?

Tags: json, file-upload

How to specify a filename and filepath as a key value pair in json?
Basically, I want to use a string which contains a json key value pair and use it to set the request stream in GetRequestStream() by using HttWebRequest.

This is what I do:

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uploadURL);
            request.Method = "POST";
            var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            string json = "  {\"filedata\":\"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\TestJeevitha1.pdf\", \"description\":\"TestUpload\"}";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            //The response from Alfresco server             
            status_code = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode;
            if (status_code == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Label1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();


            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + "Upload file failed with status: " +   status_code.ToString() + "Response: " + reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Label1.Visible = true;
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Is this piece of code:

```
string json = "{\"filedata\":\"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test\\TestJeevitha1.pdf\", \"description\":\"TestUpload\"}";
```

The right way to specify a filepath in json as a string? If, not could you please let me know.I'm very new to json and appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.
Jeevitha